# Dissecting a triangle into 4 pieces

Tags: geometry, dissection

How can I dissect a triangle into 4 piece and form a square?  I took
 A right triangle with sides 3,4,5.i was able to get a rectangle of side 3 and 2,if I dissect that I was able to get 3 squares of sides 2,1,1. I am new to dissection problems I just need to know how to approach these kind of problems

Comment: Is there a more specific question you have? do you have an example picture?

Comment: What kind of triangle?  Isosceles triangle?  Right triangle?  Or are you asking for a general-case solution?

Comment: It is a right triangle

Answer (score 3):

Solution for a right isosceles triangle.

> [image]

Solution for an equilateral triangle:

> You can dissect it via the [Dudeny Dissection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinged_dissection). Image is from Wikipedia.
>  [image]

This answer may be a partial solution. Assuming that "square" means "regular quadrilateral with equal sides", then I don't think there is a general-case solution that fits your question for all possible triangles. You may be thinking of the

> [Wallace–Bolyai–Gerwien theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace%E2%80%93Bolyai%E2%80%93Gerwien_theorem).

According to the theorem, any triangle can be dissected and rearranged into a square with equal area. However, it does not guarantee that it is dissected into 4 pieces.

Comment: Actually, it has been proved that there exists a chained - i.e where are pieces remain in a chain as in your example - disection from any convex (not sure if this is a condition) polygon to any other (convex?) polygon